# My Rails route is always going to show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have following route in my Rails project

```
resources :custom_urls, :path => '', :only => [:show, :new, :create]
```

My route is working fine for `show`, `new` and `create` action. But when ever I go to other paths e.g

```
localhost:3000/index
```

it always goes to show page. Due to this I am getting error because my instance variable in show action is not set. How can I avoid this problem? I want to get 404 when I try to go to other routes. I only want my application to route to `show`, `new` and `create` action.

Thanks in advance.

Upate

Below are my routes

```
 Prefix Verb URI Pattern    Controller#Action
      root GET  /              custom_urls#new
custom_urls POST /              custom_urls#create
new_custom_url GET  /new(.:format) custom_urls#new
custom_url GET  /:id(.:format) custom_urls#show
```

Comment: show the output of: `bundle exec rake routes` please.

Comment: I have update my question with `routes`.

Comment: The reason I am using `:path => ''` so that I can type `localhost:3000/new` rather than `localhost:3000/custom_urls/new`

Comment: yeah, i saw that later.

Comment: when you try to go to: `/index` what controller action gets called that you see in your server log?

Comment: show action us called.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your solution, you are just getting a little bit tricked by Rails behaviour. What is happening is, since you changed the default route path for :custom_urls to "",  when you access  the following url:

```
localhost:3000/index
```

The server thinks of it as

```
localhost:3000/custom_urls/index
```

So it first look for a action called "index" on your controller. Since you didn't declare it and specified that this route doesn't really exists in your route.rb, The next logical step, for rails, is  to think "index" as an ID for an object of the class "Custom_url", and because of that it triggers the show action causing the error.

Basically this logic will happen for whatever you type like this:

```
localhost:3000/XXXX
```

or this, if you change the routes.rb

```
localhost:3000/custom_urls/XXXX
```

I dont recommend the following step, but if you really want to redirect the /index to 404 you would need to create the action in routes

```
resources :custom_urls, :path => '', :only => [:show, :new, :create, :index]
```

Then inside the CustumUrlsController, create the action "index" to redirect to a 404 error

```
def index
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception? If so, it is working as expected. In dev, it shows the webconsole and in production it will display the public/404.html.

Btw, how does the user go to localhost:3000/index page? Does your app has a menu item with /index?

If you observe rake routes carefully, localhost:3000/blah (when blah is not new) is same as telling your app find me custom_url with id blah. In this case the blah is index. It could be any thing and if it is a valid id it will fetch the record. localhost:3000/new takes precedence over localhost:3000/notnew.